# once all records updated in mysql then can i restore it?

Tags: mysql, database

By mistake I have update a table without condition.

Is there any way to restore that table in MySQL?

Comment: If transaction was commited (I assume it was since it's autocommit by default) you are pretty much done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ROLLBACK` command.
 But as mentioned in the comments, if the transaction was committed, maybe you should start searching for the script that created the table.